# Android auto backup rules not well formed error

Tags: android, android-xml, android-backup-service

I have implemented a specific auto backup rules for my app following the developers documentations :

[android developers](http://android.magicer.xyz/preview/backup/index.html)

Here , they specify that you can configure this and attach it to your manifest

```xml
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"] path="string" />
    <exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"] path="string" />
</full-backup-content>
```

So I've created a new XML as the documentation said , and then I've pasted the example into my xml . However , the same example provided in the documentation doesn't compile at all :

[image]

> error: not well-formed (invalid token).

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You should probably use [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) over whatever site that is

Comment: The official docs point the same example , still not working